# Good resource to learn "PRACTICAL" OOP?

Tags: c#, oop, object

This might sound like a silly question, because if you Google `"OOPS"` or `"OOPS in C#"` you get tons of results. But.
I am aware of concepts of `OOP` like `abstraction`, `inheritance` and what not... But what I want to see is some "***practical usable example***" of it in programming. Like for `polymorphism`  you know a practical example is `Object.GetType` etc.

Some times if not many, I find myself doing something like at a button click open a connection and do some stuff, this is not `OOP` oriented from what I know, I should have a particular entity/class, and it should have a method for the stuff I am doing at button click, and then I should call that method, instead of doing all the stuff at button click.

Another example is that I just found myself loading all the projects that a employee works on, at `the txtEmployeeName.Leave` event and then fill the combo for the projects. This is not OOP oriented either, I should have class `Employee`, and a method in that which loads all the projects this employee works on, and then I should call that method at `txtEmployeeName.Leave`.

When I find or read somewhere (online or whatever) I see things like, `Vehicle` is a abstract class, and `Car` is a `Vehicle`, so it inhered from `Vehicle`, and this is `Inheritance`. We all understand that, but that's not a practical thing. Another example I found, that if we have a method `MakeSound`, and we call it an object `Cat`, it will `Purr`, but if we call the same method on `Dog`, it will `Bark`, this is `Polymorphism`.

Its good for understanding, but its not "*practical*" or you should rather say "*real programming example*". **So what I need to know is that are there any good resources (online, books or whatever) where I can read about OOP but not like in exaples I gave in previous paragraph, but some "real world programming example" that would actually have me make my code more OO?**

Comment: Study the C# libraries.  They have lots of examples of using real OO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here are some

[OOP best practice: Employee.GetCars() vs Cars.GetByEmployee()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470516/oop-best-practice-employee-getcars-vs-cars-getbyemployee)

Best practice and proper class design in object oriented language(C#)
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/232598/Best-practice-and-proper-class-design-in-object-or

Beginning C# Object-Oriented Programming
http://www.apress.com/9781430235309/

Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx

Design Pattern Tutorial
http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx/