# C# Project/task in which I could learn OOP

Tags: c#, oop

I had built several programs using C# like simple web browser with logic for addresses bar, status bar, some scripting. Simple program which I cannot explain it correctly in english, so instead of explaining I will tell pseudocode:

1. Get Values and Variables from CSV file which contains many Variables from old language
2. 3x class for each specified variables to make list
3. From lists generate excel file

Simple games in unity 3D from tutorials and some other simple programs from tutorials.

And I'm looking for a project in which I will learn interfaces, abstract class, polymorphism, inheritance, encapsulation in a practical way. All the tutorials tells the theory of it, I can understand most of them but I couldn't imagine the usage of them.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/572738/Building-an-application-using-design-patterns-and?fid=1829944&df=90&mpp=25&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&fr=26#xx0xx
This article propably is good but there is no practical data, there isn't any items on which we could work. Therefor I cannot understand why we use interfaces etc.

I have found two tutorials:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YxewTI4H2mY
youtube com/watch?v=QORB9qbsC8M

(sorry but without 10 reputation I cannot post more than 2 links)
Do you think that any of that Is a good way to learn OOP? Could you go to the last minutes of that programs and tell if that programs have good OOP code?

I love to hear any sugestions, help etc. By this time I have to say thanks to all of you who passed through this awful english question and try to answer me!

Comment: Be aware that *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501657/good-resource-to-learn-practical-oop

Answer (score 0):

One concept that lends itself to Object orientation is any sort of database of hierarchical objects. My suggestion would be a zoo.

In a zoo, you can have a main abstract class Animal. This would have basic properties that any animal has, such as the name of the animal and its date of birth. Every animal needs to eat, so an abstract function like eat() would be appropriate.

Inheriting Animal, you can have for example abstract classes Reptile, Bird, Mammal, Insect

A reptile might then contain extra information that is only valid for a reptile.

Inheriting Reptile, you can have for example non-abstract classes Crocodile, Snake, Frog, etc.

A Crocodile could then have more properties and functions that only apply to a crocodile, such as DoDeathRoll().

For the actual animals in the zoo, you then create an instance of the lowest tier of classes. So `Crocodile Humphrey = new Crocodile("Humphrey");`

Regarding interfaces, you could consider interfaces such as Pettable, Flying (both birds and bats can fly, even though they don't share any other inheritance than Animal) to make functions such as ReactToPetting() or Fly() visible.

Creating a system like this will get you very much used to working with inheritance and polymorphism.